# WMQ MFT - Redistributable Agent

Tags: agent, redistributable, websphere-mq-fte

I have knowledge on IBM MQ, but I don't have knowledge on MQ mft, in my new project they have done a setup on IBM MQ MFT Redistributable agent topology, in source and destination VM they have installed agents and cloud container MQ is running. Can someone explain how the redistributable agent work flow happens.

Comment: Here is a overview MQ Managed File Transfer https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=overview-managed-file-transfer. MFT Redistributable Pacakge is a simple way to distribute MFT. It does not require any "installation", simply unpack the tar/zip file and configure. Technically it is no different from standard installation of MQ MFT.

Comment: Thank you Shashi